# Создание расписания партий по круговой системе Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет! Я создаю систему управления соревнованиями на [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel). Я получаю участников группы с помощью отношения `Group::competitors`, и у меня есть таблица партий `personal_games`, в которой есть поля `player1` и `player2` для `id` участников. Мне нужно написать функцию контроллера `PersonalGameController`, которая бы создавала партии по круговой системе по следующим схемам:

**Для группы из 3 игроков:**
1 тур: 2-3
2 тур: 3-1
3 тур: 1-2

**Для группы из 4 игроков:**
1 тур: 1-4, 2-3
2 тур: 3-1, 2-4
3 тур: 1-2, 4-3

**Для группы из 5 игроков:**
1 тур: 2-4, 1-5
2 тур: 4-1, 5-3
3 тур: 1-3, 2-5
4 тур: 3-2, 5-4
5 тур: 1-2, 3-4

**Для группы из 6 игроков:**
1 тур: 2-4, 1-5, 3-6
2 тур: 4-1, 6-2, 5-3
3 тур: 1-3, 2-5, 4-6
4 тур: 3-2, 6-1, 5-4
5 тур: 1-2, 3-4, 5-6

Вот таблицы БД (для понимания):
`competitors`:
[image: Таблица competitors]

`personal_games` (результаты пока не заполняются, там `null`)
[image: Таблица personal_games]

Помогите, пожалуйста, придумать алгоритм, который бы выдавал партии по таким схемам. В идеале хотелось бы, чтобы он работал и для другого количества участников в группе. Заранее всем благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [round-robin алгоритм](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament) генерации всех пар.

Для иллюстрации - располагаем элементы в два ряда. Если нечётное количество - добавляем фиктивного, играющий с ним отдыхает.

Фиксируем один элемент A

На каждом круге циклически сдвигаем все элементы, кроме фиксированного, образуем новые пары

```
A B
D C
-----
A D
C B
----
A C
B D
```

Пары:

```
AD, BC 
AC, BD 
AB, CD
```

P.S.
О, я даже на PHP [что-то такое изображал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730988/844416), для нечётного количества в комментариях дополнение.

[Пример на Python](https://onlinegdb.com/jH7O43Tmp), для нечетного количества участников играющий с последним (фиктивным) отдыхает

Comment: Спасибо! Я [немного изменил](https://ideone.com/0HWmkM) код по ссылке для себя и он работает. В принципе, я могу использовать и этот вариант, но мне бы хотелось сделать так, чтобы результат совпадал с моими схемами (они взяты из регламента Кубка России по моему виду спорта), если это возможно. Не могли бы вы мне помочь это реализовать?

Comment: И ещё я пытался сделать для чётного количества как там написано, но оно работает некорректно (для трёх игроков выдаёт две партии, а не три).

Comment: Для нечётного количества надо добавить фиктивного игрока и учесть его в общем количестве. Я добавил в ответ ссылку на код на Python, в PHP нужно смотреть, чтобы деление на два выполнялось целочисленно (7/2=>3, а не округление до 4). Насчёт соответствия таблиц - не очень понятна закономерность. Вот [пример готовых таблиц](http://shogipro.narod.ru/sequenceplay.html) - там ещё другие пары.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! [Применил](https://ideone.com/4JxfhK) целочисленное деление и теперь работает как мне нужно.